# how do i identify the location of a transaction?

Tags: coinbase.com

I have an old coinbase account and can't figure out for the life of me where I would have sent the coins.  What is the best way to determine the owner or location from a bitcoin address?
14vRCiVnT4Su1akXrKmUUa3Ucf971pJXsB

Comment: Is the 14vRC your address? There's only been two transactions for that address, one was receiving the 0.01 BTC and the other the 0.01 BTC was sent to [1Facb8QnikfPUoo8WVFnyai3e1Hcov9y8T](https://blockchain.info/address/14vRCiVnT4Su1akXrKmUUa3Ucf971pJXsB)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is where it was sent.  I'm assuming i sent it to another account with a different service.

Answer (score 1):

The address you linked to only has 2 transactions for a total received of .01 BTC, which was later sent to 1Facb8QnikfPUoo8WVFnyai3e1Hcov9y8T.

Remember that the address you linked may not be the only bitcoin address you had available in your coinbase account. A wallet can provide many addresses.

Transaction info: 
https://bitcoinchain.com/block_explorer/address/14vRCiVnT4Su1akXrKmUUa3Ucf971pJXsB

As for figuring out the owner/location tied to a bitcoin address as far as I understand this is not a built in feature of bitcoin. Unless the owner has publicly attached this address to a name somewhere there is not really a way the average person can find out who owns it or where they are from.

I'm sure a hacker/government could find a way to monitor transactions on the network and gain your IP but I don't think that information is made available for the average user.

This thread may help clarify: [How do I see the IP address of a bitcoin transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/193/how-do-i-see-the-ip-address-of-a-bitcoin-transaction)