# how do I create and encrypt a dogecoin wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, encryption, wallet.dat, dogecoin

I've looked at the dogecoin wiki, but don't see any resources explaining how to actually create a wallet and encrypt it.

I'm running dogecoin-qt on Linux.

Under "much receive" on the GUI, I can add addresses.  But there's no option to encrypt which I see.

The "wow" tab says wallet, 0.000 doge (which I expect).

Where is the wallet info to read?  Is it encrypted?  How do I encrypt it?

I can find the file itself well enough:

```
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ 
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$ locate wallet.dat
/home/thufir/.dogecoin/wallet.dat
thufir@dur:~/dogecoin$
```

but I'm trying to use the GUI.

Comment: Try seeing if there is an menu item named [encrypt wallet...] in your [settings] menu.
It should open up a new screen that allows you to enter a password or passphrase to encrypt your wallet with.

Comment: no menu on my qt version

Comment: The encrypt option should be there. You miss-configured something in your build, recompile and try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep my wallet secure?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-can-i-keep-my-wallet-secure) First answer tells you how to do this with truecrypt instead of the built-in way. Could be useful to you if your menu isn't working for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

The encrypt option is under settings.

Comment: I don't have a settings option -- no menu.  (well, I would have to recompile the client, but that was the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass commands to the qt in command prompt `/path/to/dogecoin-qt <command>`

or the qt debug console (help>debug, then the console tab),

To encrypt your wallet pass the command `encryptwallet <passphrase>`

This will close the client, once you open it again you will have to enter your password before being able to send a transaction or sign a message.

Comment: I can't confirm this solution, but sounds good.